# Must Cauchy–Riemann equation hold if we only know that the partial derivatives exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-riemann-equations

Suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic function function in a neighborhood of $z_0$, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at $z_0$. Must Cauchy–Riemann equation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \mathrm{i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ hold at the point $z_0$?

If we do not assume that $f$ is differentiable as a bivariate function at $z_0$, then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are not necessarily continuous with respect to $x$ or $y$, as shown by the example $f(z) = \begin{cases} z^2\sin\dfrac{1}{z^4}, &z\neq 0\\ 0, &z=0\end{cases}$. Of course, the equation can be violated only when $z_0$ is an essential sigularity of $f$. I can't currently come up with a proof or a counter-example. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Look up the Riemann removable singularity theorem.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I know that theorem, so of course the question only concerns about the case where $z_0$ is an essential sigularity. In this case, we don't even know how $f(z_0)$ is defined since $f$ is not continuous at $z_0$.

Comment: If your partial derivatives exist at $z_0$, the function is bounded at that point (else $f(x_0, y_0)$ does not make sense when computing the partials), so it extends to a holomorphic function, no?

Comment: @CameronWilliams no, if I got my example correctly ... Another example would be $f(z) = \begin{cases} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{z^4}\right), &z\neq 0\\ 0, &z=0\end{cases}$.

Comment: Oh blerp, yep I see what you're going for now. Major brain fart on my part. I was not thinking of piecewise defined functions even though you have one in your OP! That function with the (-) in it works. The partials only tell you information along the axes, so your function can have wildly varying behavior between the axes.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, that's what causes the problem for the function :)

Comment: Another way to think of this which *might* be helpful is to think about holomorphicity as "independence of $\bar{z}$", i.e. the $\bar{z}$ derivative is $0$. If your function is holomorphic in a neighborhood of your point and piecewise defined, then the function away from your point $z_0$ does not depend on $\bar{z}$ but it does at $z_0$. If in addition the $x$ and $y$ partials exist at $z_0$, I feel that the behavior of the function is significantly constrained.

Comment: For those interested, some especially precise technical results are given in [this 29 December 2004 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/nQqSDfEADBg/m/aE-BFok_GyUJ).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Looman-Menchoff theorem is indeed a very interesting result. Thanks a lot for the link!